# Do all verbs have an honorific and humble form?

Tags: grammar, verbs, politeness, honorifics

I was reading about this phenomenon in a few places and saw, for instance, this table of transformations and substitutions for various verbs.

Is it only these common verbs which change, or do *all* verbs have a variant for the respectful and humble styles of speech?

I am aware other aspects of speech may change for honorific/humble style, but I am asking specifically about verbs.

As I understand it, all verbs have a polite form, but I am not sure about honorific and humble forms.

[image]

Comment: その表、「言う」の尊敬語が「おしゃいます」になってますね。。タイポでしょうね・・

Comment: I am new to Japanese and cannot read that yet :( Sorry.

Comment: おしゃいます in that table is a typo for お**っ**しゃいます. Is it from your textbook?

Comment: Also isn't the humble form of 住む　住んでおります。 ?

Comment: The image was taken from a random google result discussing the topic. http://cotoacademy.com/japanese-keigo/ I guess I would not be surprised if it was critically flawed, although it would serve as a good lesson to cross-check these things. At any rate that problem does not change the essence of my question.

Comment: For the table on that page, they say "In the table below, you will find the honorific and humble styles’ **special set-expressions**". You should first see this table above in *Basic rules of Keigo* - (3) : http://cotoacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/keigo11.jpg

Comment: I did see that but was unsure if that described the system fully. I'm kind of trying to find out the extent of what I need to learn.

Comment: The verbs noted as NA in the list lacks corresponding honorific or humble forms. For example, since もらう lacks the honorific form, you use that of 受け取る instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As a general rule, almost all verbs can be transformed into an honorific form, and many, but not all, can be transformed into a humble form*. The chart you pasted lists special/irregular forms. So, for verbs not listed in that chart, you can *usually* transform them into the *basic/regular* honorific/humble forms, like this:

**Honorific forms**:

> - 「お～～になる」 eg [待]{ま}つ → **お**待ち**になる**, 座{すわ}る → **お**座り**になる**, 送{おく}る → **お**送り**になる**
>     <sub>(Use the continuative form/連用形 in ～～.)</sub>
> - 「～～れる・られる」 eg 待つ → 待た**れる**, 座る → 座ら**れる**, [出掛]{でか}ける → 出掛け**られる**
>     <sub>(Use the imperfective form/未然形 in ～～. Use れる for godan verbs and られる for ichidan verbs.)</sub>

For (Sino compound noun +) する-verbs, you'd usually do like this:

> - 「ご～～になる」 eg [利用]{りよう}する → **ご**利用**になる**, [到着]{とうちゃく}する → **ご**到着**になる**
> - 「(ご)～～なさる」 eg [遠慮]{えんりょ}する → (ご)遠慮**なさる**, [結婚]{けっこん}する → (ご)結婚**なさる**
> - 「(ご)～～される)」 eg 到着する → (ご)到着**される**, 結婚する → (ご)結婚**される**

<sub>(「～～れる・られる」「～～される」 forms are considered a little less respectful than 「お/ご～～になる」「～～なさる」 forms.)</sub>

For some verbs you could also use 「ご・お～～だ/です」, eg **お**待ち**だ**, **お**[帰]{かえ}り**です**, **ご**[立腹]{りっぷく}**だ**, **ご**[到着]{とうちゃく}**です**, etc.

**Humble forms**:

> - 「お～～する」 eg 待つ → **お**待ち**する**, [呼]{よ}ぶ → **お**呼び**する**, 送る → **お**送り**する**
>     <sub>(Use the continuative form/連用形 in ～～.)</sub>

For (Sino compound noun +) する-verbs:

> - 「ご～～する」 eg 連絡{れんらく}する → **ご**連絡**する**, 案内{あんない}する → **ご**案内**する**

You could also use 「お・ご～～致{いた}します」「お・ご～～[申]{もう}し[上]{あ}げる」
 (these sound more formal / politer), eg **お**呼び**致します**, **ご**連絡**いたします**, **お**[慕]{した}い**申し上げます**, **ご**案内**申し上げます**, etc.

*Basically, the verbs that don't directly affect/influence the other interlocutor or a third party can't be turned into a humble form, eg: わかる, [着]{き}る, [死]{し}ぬ, [出席]{しゅっせき}する, [参加]{さんか}する, etc. (おわかりする, お着する, お死にする, ご出席する, ご参加する sound incorrect/strange -- 出席いたします, 参加いたします would be fine, though.)

Comment: Would you kindly tell me if 寝る, and 眠る fall under the same category as 着る and such? Is this restriction (that certain verbs cannot be made humble) related to transitivity?

Comment: @Yeti Yeah.. 「お寝する」「お眠りする」 sound incorrect/unnatural... `related to transitivity` -- Not all transitive verbs can be turned into the humble form, eg 着る is transitive but you don't say お着する... and some intransitive verbs can be used in the humble form, eg お会いする、ご同行する...