# 「ご覧ください」v.s.「ご覧をください」

Tags: particle-を, keigo

It seems that 「ご覧」 is treated as a noun (with a verb origin) in phrases such as 「ご覧**に**なる」.

One may reasonably expect that when used with 「ください / いただく」, 「ご覧」 can, or even should, be followed by 「を」.

However, 「ご覧<del>を</del>ください / いただく」 seems much more common.

Similarly, 「お待ち**を**ください / いただく」 sounds even wrong(?).

Is there a good explanation for the (kind of) compulsory leave-out of 「を」 here?

---

Or put it in another way:

**ビール**ですか

**ビールを**ください

**お持ち**ですか

**お持ち**<del>を</del>ください

I understand that generalization fails quite often in natural languages, but, instead of saying it's just how it works, is there any good explanation here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「お/ごXXいただく」 is the humble form of 「XXしてもらう」.
「お/ごXXくださる」 is the honorific form of 「XXしてくれる」. (「ください」 is the imperative form of 「くださる」.)
You normally won't insert を here.

In general, you use 「お+連用形+いただく/くださる」 for native Japanese verbs, as in:

> 「待ってもらう」→「**お**待ち**いただく**」
>   「待ってくれる」→「**お**待ち**くださる**」 <sub>(→「お待ちくださ**い**」 in imperative form)</sub>

and 「ご+名詞(語幹)+いただく/くださる」 for Sino compound する-verbs (漢語サ変動詞), as in:

> 「遠慮してもらう」→「**ご**遠慮**いただく**」
>   「利用してくれる」→「**ご**利用**くださる**」 <sub>(→「ご利用くださ**い**」 in imperative form)</sub>

---

The verb 見る is irregular; its honorific form is 「ご覧になる」, not 「お見になる」 (For regular honorific/humble forms, see [this thread](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/54417/9831)). You use this 覧 for the verb 「見る」 with 「ご～いただく」「ご～くださる」 too:

> 「見てもらう」→「ご覧いただく」
>   「見てくれる」→「ご覧くださる」 <sub>(「ご覧ください」 in imperative form)</sub>

---

To the Edit:

> お持ち<del>を</del>ください

持ち is the 連用形... It's natural for 用言 「くださる」「いただく」 to follow a 連用形, no...?

Comment: 「ご+語幹+いただく/くださる/する/いたす/申し上げる」（eg「ご利用くださる/いただく」「ご案内する/いたす/申し上げる」）に「を」がいらないのは、「サ変名詞+する」（eg「利用する」「遠慮する」「連絡する」「案内する」「勉強する」）に「を」がいらないのと同じことのような気が・・・つまり「動詞（句）」と捉えていて、「名詞+する」とか「(お/ご)名詞+いただく」とかいうふうには思わないっていうか・・

Comment: So it's also better to deem 「お持ちです」 as (a contracted form of) 「連用形（持つ → 持ち） ＋ 連用形（だ → で） ＋ 連用形（ござる → ござい） ＋ 助動詞（ます）」 rather than 「名詞化された動詞（持つ → 持ち） ＋ です」?

Comment: さあ。。「お待ちだ/です」は「お＋名詞形＋だ/です」に見えますねぇ・・　まあでも「お待ちください」「お持ちします」とかも、もともとは「お待ちをください」「お持ちをします」から来たのかもよ？「少々お待ちください」って意味で「しばしお待ち**を** 。」って言うし。　あと、「～～ **を**ご確認**を**ください」って言うと「を」が2回あって変だから「（～を）ご確認ください」なのかも？　「日本語**を**勉強**を**する」って言わないのと同じで。

Answer (score 1):

No を is necessary in your example, as it would not be grammatical.

を follows noun forms specifically.

[覧る](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%A6%A7) is a non-standard form of the verb 見る. ご覧 is a standard honorific usage. Although the ～になる construction can be preceded by both nouns and verbs, in this case ご覧 is not acting as a noun.

Common honorific (尊敬語）usages involving ご覧 are [ご覧になる and ご覧なさる](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/Japanese/miru.html). Both of these usages conjugate like non-honorific verbs. For example, 見る would adopt the te-form when placed before ください。

> 見てください　―　ご覧になってください　－　＊ご覧なさってください

＊As the なさる form is not normally used with ください。The reason for this would require a more detailed answer. Suffice to say, ご覧なさい is usually reserved to usage towards people below the speaker  in the social hierarchy (subordinates, children, etc.).

ご覧ください is an abbreviated form of ご覧になってください. As an abbreviation, it will still follow that it is acting as a verb.

As regards using it with いただく, you would not usually shorten ご覧になる to just ご覧 and would use the fuller expression of ご覧になっていただく.

> From casual to honorific:
>
> 見てくれ　→　見てください　→　ご覧ください　→　ご覧になってください　→　ご覧になっていただけませんか

This applies to the other verb you mentioned (お待ち) as well as others (お掛け, ご説明, etc.)