# Absence of て in お気をつけください

Tags: grammar, usage, nuances, expressions, て-form

I’m uncertain about the phrase お気をつけください, which I found where I would have expected お気をつけてください. Assuming it’s not a typo is it 尊敬語？ Should I understand the honorific お  as qualifying 気  only or the whole 気をつけ ？and would お気をつけてください be grammatically wrong,  simply unusual , or something completely different?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

お気をつけください is a politer/more respectful way of saying 気をつけてください.

It's the honorific [「お + noun form/連用形 + ください」 form](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/58245/9831).

Examples:

- 「待ってください。」 "Please wait"
  (noun form/連用形 of 待つ is 待ち) → 「お+待ち+ください。」
- 「話してください。」 "Please speak"
  (noun form/連用形 of 話す is 話し) → 「お+話し+ください。」
- 「注意してください。」 "Please be careful"
  (for kango you generally use ご) → 「ご+注意+ください。」

Likewise:

- 「気をつけてください。」 "Please take care"
  (turning 気をつける into the noun form/連用形) → 「お+気をつけ+ください。」

Comment: Then shouldn't there be two お's?  「お気+を+お+つけください」？  I thought the お in お気 was 美化語?

Comment: @istrasci 「お薬を**お**飲みください」みたいな感じですね。普通は「お気をおつけください」とは言わないですね。。 I think 気をつける is treated as one verb phrase.