# Meaning of おまちする

Tags: translation, word-usage, keigo

From: https://www.serebii.net/blackwhite/subwaymaster.png

Context: The character who says this to you (the player) is on the subway along with you. They are also about to battle you.

> ようこそ　おまちしておりました！

おまち means "long awaited" from what I can tell, but I'm having trouble understanding exactly what おまちする would mean. Does it mean "to wait a long time"?

What exactly would the full sentence mean then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

お待ちする is the humble form (謙譲語) of 待つ. So お待ちしておりました is the humble way of saying 待っていました, "I was waiting / I've been waiting (for you)." (おります is the humble form of いる.)

For more on the humble form 「お＋連用形+する」, please refer to: [Do all verbs have an honorific and humble form?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54416/9831)

> ようこそ　お待ちしておりました！
>   "Welcome! I've been waiting for you!"

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot! Thanks. I originally thought おりました　came from おりる（to alight）.