# 謙譲語 (Kenjougo) Beginner question

Tags: politeness

Good day,

I'm currently studying Japanese in a school here in Tokyo and I'm on my 5th month already here. Problem is that the lesson here is sometimes too fast, which is why I need to use other resources such as this website to learn. Our lesson is currently about `謙譲語`. I saw in the vocabulary that `いたします` is the humble equivalent of `する`, but I'm having trouble figuring out when to use it.

In the Minna no Nihongo Book 2nd Ed. that we're currently using,

```
1st and 2nd verb group
お＋します 

Example
よていをお知らせします
かばんをお持ちします

3rd verb group
ご＋します
ご案内します
中止の場合はご連絡します
```

I was wondering where `いたします` fits in the actual lesson, as I cannot find the actual usage in the book, all I know is that I should use it on some events like when entering a room `失礼いたします`, or `お願いいたします` but I need some explanation to further understand it's usages. Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Would this be of some help? : https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/54417/9831

Comment: I'd like to reconfirm something.. so basically, 
`案内します -> ご案内します -> ご案内いたします`. Wherein the first is the regular masu form, the second changing it to humble form, the third form being the super duper humble 'senpai teach me' form?

Comment: そおですね・・・　ご案内いたします is more humble and politer than ご案内します, but not so much as *the super duper humble senpai form*..  ご案内申し上げます is even politer.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation, it's one of those things that Minna No Nihongo sometimes lacks. A really big help!

Answer (score 1):

謙譲語　は　humble form。

It is used while speaking to the superior by humble ourself.

Instead of giving respect to the superior by humble ourself it will automatically give respect to the superior.

しますはいたします。

勉強します　－　勉強いたします。

お願いします　-　お願いいたします。

目上の人と話すとき使います。