# おタバコお吸いになりますか の意味は何ですか?

Tags: grammar

Why is になりますか used in this sentence? How is it different from おタバコを吸いますか？

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/54417/9831

Answer (score 1):

The construction `おVERBになる`is a standard honorific pattern in Japanese. It is used as a generic verbal honorific where there is no special honorific like いらっしゃる, 召し上がる, おっしゃる, etc. The verb is in the continuative form (連用形 = ますform without the ます). Other examples of honorifics in that form:

> 聞く -> お聞きになる to listen
> 帰る -> お帰りになる to go home
> 読む -> お読みになる to read